# Using a Macro to compare 3 out of 7 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 cells with a variety of Letter contained. What I could do with having is a macro that will overwrite the contents if 3 of the cells containing a 'H'.

e.g.

Cells a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

if a,b and c contain H then cells d,e,f,g,and h change to contain X

otherwise clear cell contents

below is how I've written this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.

Set KeyCells = Range("D5:BD359")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(KeyCells.Address)) Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False

a = 15
b = 45
c = 105
d = 155
e = 210
f = 260
g = 315
h = 345

For x = 0 To 4

For i = 5 To 54

If Cells(a + x, i) = "H" And Cells(b + x, i) = "H" And Cells(c + x, i) = "H" Then
    If Cells(d + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(d + x, i) = "X"
    End If
    If Cells(e + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(e + x, i) = "X"
    End If
    If Cells(f + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(f + x, i) = "X"
    End If
    If Cells(g + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(g + x, i) = "X"
    End If
    If Cells(h + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(h + x, i) = "X"
    End If

Else
    If Cells(a + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(a + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(b + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(b + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(c + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(c + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(d + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(d + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(e + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(e + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(f + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(f + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(g + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(g + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(h + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(h + x, i).ClearContents
    End If

End If
Next i
Next x

Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

I can accomplish this using IF functions but it will take days to write it.
(I have more than 7 cells but the for loop to compare all the others)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can extend this to all other 55 combinations?

Comment: Why will it take days to write an if loop?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need a better explanation.

Comment: So you have seven cells, and if exactly three of them contain "H", you want to set the remaining four cells to "X"?

Comment: 8 cells now but yes, I feel there should be a better way that writing out 56 different if functions

Comment: So write one loop, `1 to 8`, to see if you have exactly three cells equal to "H", and if so, go to another loop, also `1 to 8`, where set every cell to "X" if it's `<> "H"`?

Comment: Couldn't you use `Application.WorkSheetFunction.CountIf(...)` to count how many contain H - if the result is 3 then use FIND and FINDNEXT to get the location of the three cells and change everything else.  Edit:  Although with only 8 cells it will be just as fast to use a loop.

Comment: GSerg, could you elaborate on the 'to see if you have exactly three cells equal to "H" ' bit as that might be the bit i'm missing, at the moment I am try to use the 'AND' function.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do without being able to see the data. Please upload a screenshot of your data to imgur and post it here. I will help you if you can do this. Thanks!

Comment: @RamsesNiblick You have a counter and increment it each time you encounter H in a cell. Then you see if you have accumulated `3`. Or you use `CountIf(...)` as Darren suggested.

Comment: Thanks all! CountIF(...) has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim HCount As Long

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.

Set KeyCells = Range("D5:BD359")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(KeyCells.Address)) Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False

a = 15
b = 45
c = 105
d = 155
e = 210
f = 260
g = 315
h = 345

For x = 0 To 4

For i = 5 To 54

HCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(a + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(b + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(c + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(d + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(e + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(f + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(g + x, i), "H") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(h + x, i), "H")

If HCount = 3 Then
    If Cells(a + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(a + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(a + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(b + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(b + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(b + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(c + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(c + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(c + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(d + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(d + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(d + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(e + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(e + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(e + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(f + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(f + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(f + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(g + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(g + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(g + x, i).Locked = True
    End If
    If Cells(h + x, i) = "" Then
    Cells(h + x, i) = "X"
    Cells(h + x, i).Locked = True
    End If

Else
    If Cells(a + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(a + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(a + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(b + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(b + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(b + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(c + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(c + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(c + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(d + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(d + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(d + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(e + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(e + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(e + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(f + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(f + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(f + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(g + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(g + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(g + x, i).ClearContents
    End If
    If Cells(h + x, i) = "X" Then
    Cells(h + x, i).Locked = False
    Cells(h + x, i).ClearContents
    End If

End If

Next i
Next x

Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

This is being used to ensure only 3 members of the team are able to book holiday at once. The X is simply linked to conditional formatting and the sheet protecting locked cells so they cant be selected.